# Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified Reference when transferring values from sheet 2 to sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

the ranges in my data should be correct, as they worked with copy, however I'm just trying to get the values in the specified ranges in `sheets(2)` to `sheets(1)`

```
Private Sub insertData(RowStartData1 As Long, RowNum1 As Long)
' RowStartData1 is where the row the data starts on.
' RowNum1 is the row num - 1 where data should be inserted

Dim ColNum As Integer

RowNum1 = RowNum1 + 1
' adds one to row num so that insertion happens at right place
For ColNum = 2 To 9
        Sheets(1).Range(.Cells(RowNum1, ColNum), .Cells(RowNum1 + 5, ColNum)).Value = 
Sheets(2).Range(.Cells(RowStartData1, 4), .Cells(RowStartData1 + 5, 4)).Value

    RowStartData1 = RowStartData1 + 6

Next ColNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code won't compile because you're missing a `With` block.

Comment: Something like `With ActiveSheet` (or other sheet) above your `For ColNum` statement, and then make sure there's and `End With` after the `Next`.

Comment: So, whatever you did for this to "work" with Copy, you did not do the same thing here, because the code you show above will not work with Copy (or anything) :)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You're getting a compile error. You need to qualify your `.Cells` either explicitly or in a `With` block, like:

```
With ActiveSheet ' ## Modify as needed

    ' adds one to row num so that insertion happens at right place
    For ColNum = 2 To 9
            Sheets(1).Range(.Cells(RowNum1, ColNum), .Cells(RowNum1 + 5, ColNum)).Value = _
    Sheets(2).Range(.Cells(RowStartData1, 4), .Cells(RowStartData1 + 5, 4)).Value

        RowStartData1 = RowStartData1 + 6

    Next ColNum

End With
```